# Does @2x for retina work on all images, and how do i test for a retina display?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have 3 short questions, very related:

1. How do i detect if the user is using a retina device?
2. I want to save an image inside my app in documents, if i detect that they're using a retina display phone and save the image ending in `@2x.jpg` will it work as it does with imported images, where it'll automatically go for that one instead on a retina device?
3. If i were to reference an image which didn't exist, but a `@2x.jpg` version existed, would it go to that by default?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Use `[UIScreen mainScreen].scale`, it's `2.f` when it's a retina screen.
2. I'm not sure, but I think it'll automatically detect `@2x`-versions here too (as long as you use `UIImage` to load them).
3. If it's a retina screen, it'll look to the `@2x`-version first, if it doesn't exist, it'll fallback to the default-version. If that version doesn't exist, it'll return `nil`. A non retina screen however, will never look to the `@2x`-version.

You call it a `x2.jpg`-file, however, it isn't:

- Your default file is something like `background.png`.
- Then your retina file should be like `background@2x.png`.
- You load the image using `UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"];`.
- In most situations you don't need to know if it's a retina screen, iOS will handle this.

Comment: You're welcome. Also note that these images can't be `jpg`s (AFAIK). They need to be `png`s, I didn't know if I made that clear.

Comment: Ah, so UIImageJPEGRepresentation is useless for this then?

Comment: You mean when you save the image to your documents-folder? You should use `UIImagePNGRepresentation` then ;)!